# fields are set to null in model if not bound to spring form

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc

In Spring form if not all the fields of model are bound to form fields. On submit the result model gets null in the model fields not bound with form fields. I want that in controller when I receive the request all the fields of model which were not bound to form keep their value.
I know one way to achieve this is to put hidden fields and bind such properties to them. 
What are the other possible ways to solve this and best of each such solutions . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain the original object state somewhere:

1. Session (use @SessionAttributes) - this is the general solution
2. Get it from the database before you write it back (use @ModelAttribute on a method)
3. Store it on the client (hidden form vars)

You also don't want to overwrite the values with nulls:

1. use an @InitBinder method to set the allowedFields or disallowedFields on a DataBinder
2. create a Form Backing Object just for this form with the fields you need and copy those values to the entity (consider [Dozer](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer))

Answer (score 0):

You should add "types" element to your `@SessionAttributes("anEntity")` annotation in order properties of attributes to be kept; e.g.

```
@SessionAttributes(types = AnEntity.class, names = "anEntity")
```